# Change class with ng-click in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I need two buttons of a kind that can change the class of an element. Each button represent a different class.

I try to pass $index in the ng-click but it seems to not be working correctly.. Any suggestions would be much appreciated! :-)

Some styling

```
<style>
.class1 {color: red;}
.class2 {color: green;}
</style>
```

The view

```
    <div ng-model="myClasses">

    <a href="#" ng-click="itemClick($index)">1'eren</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="itemClick($index)">2'eren</a>
    <p class="{{myClasses}}">Torben {{myClasses}}</p>

    </div>
```

And my Angular

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.myClasses = "class0";


      $scope.itemClick = function ($index){
        if ($index == 1){
          $scope.myClasses = "class1";
        } else if ($index == 2) {
          $scope.myClasses = "class2";
        } else {
          $scope.myClasses = "class1";
        }
      };
    });
  </script>
```

[A plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/boQa228Aiohx7QdvjeTP?p=preview)

Comment: What is `<div ng-model="myClasses">` supposed to do? Placed like this, it has absolutely no relevance to the remaining code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$index is not defined in view(it mainly defined inside ng-repeat directive). so you can do like this. just replace html code to this:

```
<div ng-model="myClasses">

    <a href="#" ng-click="itemClick(1)">1'eren</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="itemClick(2)">2'eren</a>
    <p ng-class="{{myClasses}}">Torben {{myClasses}}</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Holy jesus, of couse... Almost too obvious! Guess that happens when your mind determines to solve a problem in a certain way. Anyways, it works perfectly, thanks a lot Mukund!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xONDG2?p=preview) is the updated plunk, showing how to do it in the proper way.

```
 <div>

<br><br><br>
<a href="#" ng-click=activeClass='class1'>1'eren</a>
<a href="#" ng-click=activeClass='class2'>2'eren</a>
<p ng-class="activeClass">Torben {{myClasses}}</p>
```

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);  

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // default class
  $scope.activeClass = "class0";

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-class`

```
<div ng-model="myClasses">
    <a href="#" ng-click="itemClick(1)">1'eren</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="itemClick(2)">2'eren</a>
    <p ng-class="myClasses">Torben {{myClasses}}</p>
</div>
```